# Unterschiede zwischen „verbinden“ und „anschließen“

Tags: english-to-german, difference

Jedes Mal, wenn ich “to connect” in einem Satz im Deutschen benutzen will, muss ich eine Weile denken, welches Wort für eine bestimmte Situation geeignet ist.

Da die englische Sprache in vielen Fällen ganz locker ist, kann man “to connect” verwenden, wenn man zwei greifbare oder ungreifbare Dinge verbindet; aber wenn ich mich nicht irre, ist es anders im Deutschen und man muss genau definieren, was man sagen will.

Eine Antwort mit Beispielen wird sehr geschätzt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Verbinden* impliziert im Gegensatz zu *anschließen* mehr, dass beide Teile gleichwertig sind. Beim Anschließen ist das, was angeschlossen wird, oft kleiner bzw. unwichtiger und ordnet sich der Situation unter.

- Klar wird der Unterschied z.B., wenn sich Mächte verbinden bzw. sich eine Macht der anderen anschließt.
- Schließt man einen Drucker an, wird er "nur" zum EDV-System hinzugefügt. Wird der Drucker mit dem PC verbunden, erhält man aus 2 technischen Geräten "das" Drucksystem.
- Das (wegtragbare) Fahrrad wird an den (unverrückbaren) Laternenpfahl angeschlossen, d.h. der Pfahl ist hier "mächtiger".
- Auch beim medizinischen Verband wird das Ganze als Einheit wiederhergestellt/zusammengehalten.

Im Engl. hätte man entsprechend: combine, unite <=> add, append

Comment: Eine sehr effektive Methode, den Unterschied zwischen den Wörtern zu merken. **Sie schließen ein Kartenlesegerät an einen Computer an** (Computer ist mächtiger -> anschließen) ----

**Künstler und Schriftsteller aus verschiedenen Weltgegenden verbinden ihre Arbeit zu einer Art Gesamtkunstwerk** (Gleichwertig -> verbinden)

Answer (score 1):

### Verbinden

Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbinden) hat »verbinden« vier verschiedene Bedeutungen:

1. Eine Wunde mit einer Binde abdecken oder mit einem Verband versorgen.

   > Der Sanitäter **verbindet** einen verwundeten Soldaten.
   >   Der Sanitäter **verbindet** das verletzte Bein.
2. Mehrere Dinge zu einem Gefüge vereinen oder in eine enge Beziehung bringen.

   > Diese gemeinsame Erinnerung **verbindet** mich mit dir.
   >   Der Drucker muss noch mit dem Rechner **verbunden** werden.
3. *reflexiv*: sich vereinen (für Dinge oder Personen), eine Beziehung eingehen, auch: eine chemische Verbindung eingehen

   > Fürst Heinrich **verband sich** mit Baron von Stein um gemeinsam gegen den König zu kämpfen.
   >   Wasserstoff **verbindet sich** mit Schwefel zu einem übel riechendem Gas.
4. einen Anrufer am Telefon zu einem Gesprächspartner weiterleiten

   > »Können Sie mich bitte mit Mag. Kaltengeber **verbinden**?«
   >   »Ich glaube, sie sind falsch **verbunden**.«

---

### anschließen

»Anschließen« ist ein teilbares Verb:
Richtig: Ich schließe mich an, ich bin angeschlossen.
Falsch: <del>Ich anschließe mich, ich bin geanschlossen.</del>

Hier listet [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/anschlie%C3%9Fen) sogar fünf Bedeutungen auf:

1. sich zu einer Gruppe gesellen

   > Darf ich mich euch **anschließen**?
   >   »Wir sollten die Ostmark an das Deutsche Reich **anschließen**.«
2. sich mit seiner Meinung anderen anschließen, zustimmen

   > »Ich möchte mich dem Vorredner **anschließen**, ...«
   >   »Dem kann ich mich nur voll inhaltlich **anschließen**.«
3. auf etwas folgen

   > Der Wartezeit am Grenzbalken **schloss** sich die Wartezeit im Ausnahmelager **an**.
   >   Seinem langen Krankenstand **schließt** sich jetzt die Phase der Rehabilitation **an**.
4. eine (elektrische) Verbindung herstellen

   > »**Schließen** Sie die Lampe an eine Steckdose **an**.«
   >   Der Drucker ist an den Computer **angeschlossen**.
5. Etwas mit einem Schloss an etwas anderem befestigen

   > Erwin **schloss** ein Fahrrad am Laternenpfahl **an**.

---

Wie man sieht, beinhalten beide Wörter Bedeutungen, mit denen man beschreiben kann, dass z.B. ein Drucker mit einem Computer verbunden bzw. an ihn angeschlossen ist.

Wenn sich aber eine Person einer Gruppe anschließt, muss sie sich mit den anderen Mitgliedern der Gruppe nicht unbedingt verbunden fühlen:

> Walter schloss sich der Reisegruppe nur widerwillig an. Aber anders war es ihm nicht möglich, nach Nordkorea einzureisen.

Auch das Gegenteil ist möglich:

> Ihr habt die gleichen Ideen und Ziele wie ich. Ich fühle mich euch sehr verbunden. Trotzdem will ich mich euch nicht anschließen. Meine Kinder würden mir das nie verzeihen.

Es kommt also sehr darauf an, was man ganz konkret verbinden oder anschließen will.

Comment: Man kann sich aber an eine Frau binden, der man sich nicht verbunden fühlt. Das Fühlen ist also ein falsches Kriterium. Allerdings, wenn zwei Gruppen sich verbinden wird keine Dominanz/Führerschaft ausgedrückt, anders, als wenn eine der anderen sich anschließt.